# Is the use of "shut up" pertinent?

Tags: word-usage

I want to know whether the use of 'shut up' (ex. Okay. I'll shut up) is appropriate when you have to make an apology statement officially.

Comment: Do you mean to ask if the use of the phrase _shut up_ is rude? Typically, _pertinent_ means relevant. _Impertinent_ means rude.

Answer (score 1):

"Shut up" is forceful and rude when applied to someone else. It is casual when applied to yourself.  It should not be part of an official and formal apology.

By saying "I'll shut up" you imply that the person that you are apologising to has told you to "shut up".  You imply that the person that you are apologising to has been rude to you.  You imply that you are not really sorry, but just following orders.  This is why it is not appropriate in this context.

Answer (score 0):

"Shut up" as a command given to someone is certainly impolite. You can say among co-workers and friends "be quiet, stay quite, be silent" followed by "please". In formal occasions, you can say "I will have to ask you to be silent", "I may have to  ask you to be quiet". In that way, you don't directly tell the person to be quiet, but you just express your intentions.

"I'll shut up" is not necessarily pertinent because it is not directed to someone else. However, the expression is still informal; something you can use among co-workers and friends. In formal occasions you may want to say "I'll be quiet... etc".

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I corrected them.

Comment: I tried to ask for clarity above, but the word "pertinent" is being confused for its antonym, "impertinent," which means "rude." I've only ever hear "pertinent" to mean "relevant."

Comment: I changed the word. Thanks.

Comment: @TedPal Impertinent also means "irrelevant". It has two completely different meanings and usage.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Yes, that is technically true! The primary definition of "impertinent," however, is rude, and I can't say I've really ever encountered "impertinent" in the wild as meaning "irrelevant." I've probably heard, "This is not pertinent to the discussion!" but even that is somewhat rare, IMO. The title question is better posed as the following:  "Is the use of 'shut up' rude?" It's much more clear and leaves less ambiguity.